# i can't find the download button for MOTODEVstudio at the Motorola website

Tags: motodev-studio

Many other websites give this http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/us-en/motodev_lp.html? but i couldn't find where is the download button for MOTODEVstudio

Answer (score 1):

It might be a rather old answer but to lighten things up there was this weblog which clarified what happened to [Motodev](http://www.androidcentral.com/portions-motodev-studio-android-open-sourced-and-moved-android-repository):

> Motorola has broken off part of their core build system, known as MOTODEV Studio for Android, and merged it into the Android Open Source Project. Previously, the closed-source Motorola tools were an alternative to a standard Eclipse IDE setup, which allowed key features like easy localization, drag and drop of shared code snippets, and browsing and manipulation of SQL databases through Motorola's tool.
>
> With the new merging of the core plugins to the AOSP, developers can now build and use the tools through Eclipse, which is by far the most popular IDE for Android development. Motorola has full instructions for getting the code via GIT, building it, and integrating the plugins into an Eclipse workspace. See the source links below.

However,you may download differenet versions of Motodev from [sourceforge.com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/motodev.motorola/files/).

Answer (score 0):

On the Motorola home page, click on support, developers.
On the navigation pane, click on download sdk.
There are two versions of the sdk bundle.